# JFrame text components not showing up properly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, preferredsize

I was playing around with JFrame today and had trouble getting a JButton component to display text properly. The text displayed in JButton is cut off at the end. I tried resizing the JButton component in order to make sure that the text could fit, but the same problem occurred. The problem looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Frame");
        jFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(jFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setLocation(400, 400);
        jFrame.add(new Drawable(jFrame));
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is the other class in another .java file.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Drawable extends JPanel {
    private JButton button;
    private JFrame jFrame;
    public Drawable(JFrame jFrame) {
        this.jFrame = jFrame;
        button = new JButton("This text does not show properly");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));
        button.setLocation(jFrame.getWidth() / 2 - 50, jFrame.getHeight() / 2 - 12);
        this.add(button);
    }
}
```

I understand that this might be a problem with my project's setup, so if anyone needs me to post it I can do so.

Comment: Allow the button to size gracefully depending on the text inside (don't force it's size through `setPreferredSize`). You are limiting it's size, which is why your text isn't fitting

Comment: Don't set the size and location, let the layout manager take care of that. Remove those 2 lines and if it works for you, then look into the correct layout manager for you depending on the rest of the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the statement

```
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 25));
```

which is being used by the panel's layout manager to constrain the button width